# Can I use SharePoint JSOM in a regular ASPX page?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to use the JSOM API but I don't want to create a web part(Add-in).
Can I use JSOM directly on regular page? 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, add a script editor web part and add your code in there. I think you can even use a content editor web part for this

Answer (score 0):

Compare to JSOM, you might consider to use REST API which might give you flexibility. Another way you might think about is to through SharePoint REST API instead of JSOM.